# Parameters in Clojure functions

Tags: clojure

I have a function that works like that:

```
(the-function [one] [two] [three])
```

and I need a function that calls the-function.

I tried with `[& args]` but it doesn't seem to pass the arguments correctly.

If it helps, the-function is like the create-table of MySQL found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/JDBC_Examples)

EDIT:
my function that is not working is like this:

```
(defn my-function [& args]
   (the-function args))
```

And I want to be able to do:

```
(my-function [one] [two] [three])
```

and call **the-function** with these arguments

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want your function to call the-function how exactly?

Comment: @Jon: Your edit is even more confusing.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's a stupid question and that makes it even more difficult to express it correctly.

Comment: @Jon: From your profile Python seems to be your primary language. Try to express what you want to do, with the help of Python. We'll try to tell you how to do it in Clojure.

Comment: Thanks @MF! Seems that the answer was just an apply :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, what you want is this:

```
(defn my-function [& args] (apply the-function args))
```

Apply applies a function to a set of arguments in a sequence as if they were individual arguments.

Answer (score 2):

apply is the function-calling-function,, eg:

```
(defn add-three [x y z] (+ x y z))

(add-three 1 2 3)
(apply add-three '(1 2 3))
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question.

Is destructturing what you need?

```
(defn the-function [[one two three]]
  (println (str one two three)))

(defn myfunction [& args]
   (the-function args))
```